# Visual Studio: Clicking on items in list view is not called SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm developing a web application in visual studio 2010.

I've a list view and want the list box selectindexchange event to be fired when the user select a different item. but it is not working, as the page is not even refreshing. am i missing something?

Just to add some clarity to this question for future references:

1. I was using C#
2. Using a List Box from the visual studio toolbox.

`<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:ListBox>`

Under the Properties of the ListBox1, the `SelectedIndexChanged` property is set to `ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`.

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ...some logic here...
        }
```

Comment: hi. may i know what is wrong with my question? would appreciate any feedback on how i should phrase my question.

Comment: There's _looooads_ of information missing here: what technologies? WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET? How did you subscribe to the event? Via VS interface or custom attachment in code? What does it have to do with Visual Studio, per se?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment, he has mentioned "web application" in his question, so according to me its enough to say an asp.net application

Comment: You might post some code. I doubt anyone will be able to guess what your problem is without more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be left 
 `autopostback="true"`.

Comment: AutoPostBack is not a property of ListView.

Comment: @csl where is my up vote and accept the ans if its work.Thanks D:)